Notation issues - Arc length over manifold
Hi I'm working on some notes where there's this little excursus on differential geometry, topic is arc length. In the first part arc length over $\Bbb R^n$ is defined using the limit of small segment approximating the curve so we have
$$ds = \sqrt{dx_1^2+\dots + dx_n^2} \label{eq_1}\tag{1}$$
now we use the relation $d\textbf x = \dot{\textbf x}dt$, substituting in $\eqref{eq_1}$
$$ds=\sqrt{\dot x_1^2+\dots+\dot x_n^2}dt\label{eq_2}\tag{2}$$
arc length is the sum of all this small pieces so
$$l(\gamma) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\label{eq_3}\tag{3}\sqrt{\dot x_1^2+\dots+\dot x_n^2}dt$$
and to me it's fine - notation wise and heuristically. Issues came when we transport everything on a manifold, a point $\bf x$ is described by local coordinates $q_1,\dots,q_m$ and
$$d\textbf x = \dot{\textbf{x}}dt = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial \bf x}{\partial q_j}dq_j\label{eq_4}\tag{4}$$
on the notes it's written that
$$ds^2 = \bigg (\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial \bf x}{\partial q_j}dq_j\bigg)^2\label{eq_5}\tag{5}$$
now if I look to what's in $\eqref{eq_2}$, to me $\eqref{eq_5}$ should be
$$ds^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\bigg (\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial  x_i}{\partial q_j}dq_j\bigg)^2\label{eq_6}\tag{6}$$
is one a semplification for notation in $\eqref{eq_6}$ or am I missing the point? Thank you for your help.

It is the same thing. They are thinking of $d\textbf x$ as a 'vector' of differentials and  $ds^2=d\textbf x^2=d\textbf x\cdot d\textbf x$. If you substitute (4) for $d\textbf x$ in $d\textbf x^2$ you'll get their (5), but if you write the dot product explicitly in coordinates you'll get your (6).
